# Does Google Cloud Compute Engine pricing depend on processor usage?

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine, price

I've been using the Google Cloud Compute Engine for the past couple of months, but haven't had to pay for anything yet due their 60-day crediting system. However now that I'm considering actually paying for the service, I'm trying to get a better sense of how the pricing structure works.

I understand that different machine types have different per-hour costs, and that these per-hour costs can differ depending on various discounts like the [sustained use discount](https://cloud.google.com/pricing/philosophy/). But one thing I'm still not totally clear on is whether things like processor usage, or RAM usage, or SSD usage have any bearing on the cost, or whether cost is solely dependent on how long a given instance is up and running.

For example, should I expect to see any difference in overall cost over the course of a month between two constantly running [n1-standard-4](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing) servers if one of them is churning away at 100% on all four of its cores 24/7, while the other sits mostly idle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't. See the [pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/), which doesn't take CPU usage into account. The sustained use discount is based on how long the machine runs.